# Getting error when updating a Gridview row in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when I update a row in a Gridview. I was unable to figure out after hours of research.

This small project is for using the Cache for working with disconnected data access.

Here is the code:

```
private void GetDataFromDB()
    { 
        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TST"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(CS);
        string strSelectQry = "Select * From tblStudents";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(strSelectQry, conn);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "Students");     // fill dataset with records from select query and name table "Students" (can name whatever you like).

        ds.Tables["Students"].PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] {ds.Tables["Students"].Columns["ID"] };     

        Cache.Insert("DATASET", ds, null, DateTime.Now.AddHours(24), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);  

        gvStudents.DataSource = ds;
        gvStudents.DataBind();

    }


protected void gvStudents_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Cache["DATASET"] != null)
        {
            DataSet ds = (DataSet)Cache["DATASET"];
            DataRow dr = ds.Tables["Students"].Rows.Find(e.Keys["ID"]);   // get the row thats being edited

            dr["Name"] = e.NewValues["Name"];               // update fields in datarow
            dr["Gender"] = e.NewValues["Gender"];
            dr["TotalMarks"] = e.NewValues["TotalMarks"];

            // store the dataset back into the cache
            Cache.Insert("DATASET", ds, null, DateTime.Now.AddHours(24), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);

            gvStudents.EditIndex = -1;      // take row out of edit mode
            GetDataFromCache();             // update gridview with updated dataset from cache
        }
    }
```

I'm getting the object reference error in the "gvStudents_RowUpdating(...)" method on the line: dr["Name"] = e.NewValues["Name"];

Comment: Have you tried to debug the app and checked what is null (dr should be null)?

Comment: @Gusman Yes i did debug it and dr is null. But dr should contain the data from the Gridview row that is being edited

Comment: you're searching dr on your cache through an ID, check if you have received the ID and if the cache is really working.

Comment: @Gusman I checked the e.Keys and there is no data. Values are empty...I don't see why. I also checked the "ds" and it shows 7 for the count which the table does have 7 rows, but I can't view the rows in the ds.

Answer (score 0):

I would try populating your data keys when you databind, and then reading from them in your RowUpdating method to get the current ID. So, after `gvStudents.DataBind();`, add

```
gvStudents.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "ID" };
```

Then, in your RowUpdating method, get the current ID from the data keys:

```
var currentID = gvStudents.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value;
```

Comment: Doing that will only give me the ID of the row. I need to have access to the entire row that is being updated or changed in the form of a DataRow so I can update.

Comment: Correct, you'd still need this line:
`DataRow dr = ds.Tables["Students"].Rows.Find(e.Keys["ID"]);`
Just replace `e.Keys["ID"]` with `gvStudents.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value`.